# single query to find difference in values in the three tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Am having three similar tables

- test_dev
- test_qmg
- test_prod

All the tables have same columns. i want single query to find difference in values in the three tables.
example:

```
select * from test_dev  
minus
select * from test_qmg
minus
select * from test_prod
```

column names are same for all three tables. I want to find the difference in values in column.

```
select VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY from visa_type_lk where visa_type_id=1 select VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY from visa_type_lk_qmg where visa_type_id=1 select VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY from visa_type_lk_prod where visa_type_id=1
```

here validity_days_before_entry,validity_days_before_entry column will change. i want to find that difference

Comment: So do you mean, for item 1, you want this value: test_dev.column1 - test_qmg.column1 - test_prod.column1?
And for item 2, you want test_dev.column1 - test_qmg.column1 - test_prod.column1 for the item 2 record? I think it would be easier to understand the question if you post an example of the tables, and the result you want.

Comment: yes test_dev have one value  the same column is having different value in test_qmg.    Both tables test_dev and test_qmg will have common id

Comment: select VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY from visa_type_lk  where visa_type_id=1

select VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY from visa_type_lk_qmg  where visa_type_id=1

select VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY from visa_type_lk_prod  where visa_type_id=1               here validity_days_before_entry,validity_days_before_entry column will change. i want to find that difference

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

> SELECT dev.visa_type_id, 
>   (dev.VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY - qmg.VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY - prod.VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY) as difference_before, 
>   (dev.VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY - qmg.VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY - prod.VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY) as difference_after
>
> FROM  visa_type_lk dev INNER JOIN visa_type_lk_qmg qmg ON dev.visa_type_id = qmg.visa_type_id 
>   INNER JOIN visa_type_lk_prod prod ON qmg.visa_type_id = prod.visa_type_id
>
> WHERE dev.visa_type_id =1

Here's a link to an SQL fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56e16/2

Are you sure this is really what you want to do though? I can't imagine how this data would be useful. By the way, all of these tables are in one database, right?

Comment: Thanks for your response. am looking  for version difference in three  tables. i got thst by following query

Comment: @FrancisJohn I think you proposed an edit to my answer by mistake. If that is the query that worked for you, add it as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
MIN(environment_name) as environment_name,VISA_TYPE_ID,
  VISA_TYPE_EN,
  VISA_TYPE_AR,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY,
  STAY_DAYS,
  STAY_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_BORDER_VISA,
  IS_MULTIPLE_ENTRY_VISA,
  VIOLATION_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_ARCHIVED,
  JOB_CLOSE_AFTER_DAYS,
  IS_ALLOWED_FOR_ESTAB_QUOTA, 
  REPLACE_WITH_VISA_TYPE_ID
FROM
(
   SELECT
   'development' as environment_name, VISA_TYPE_ID,
  VISA_TYPE_EN,
  VISA_TYPE_AR,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY,
  STAY_DAYS,
  STAY_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_BORDER_VISA,
  IS_MULTIPLE_ENTRY_VISA,
  VIOLATION_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_ARCHIVED,
  JOB_CLOSE_AFTER_DAYS,
  IS_ALLOWED_FOR_ESTAB_QUOTA, 
  REPLACE_WITH_VISA_TYPE_ID
   FROM visa_type_lk A
   where visa_type_id in (select visa_type_id from visa_type_lk_prod)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
   'production' as environment_name, VISA_TYPE_ID,
  VISA_TYPE_EN,
  VISA_TYPE_AR,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY,
  STAY_DAYS,
  STAY_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_BORDER_VISA,
  IS_MULTIPLE_ENTRY_VISA,
  VIOLATION_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_ARCHIVED,
  JOB_CLOSE_AFTER_DAYS,
  IS_ALLOWED_FOR_ESTAB_QUOTA, 
  REPLACE_WITH_VISA_TYPE_ID
   FROM visa_type_lk_prod B

)
tmp
GROUP BY VISA_TYPE_ID,
  VISA_TYPE_EN,
  VISA_TYPE_AR,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_BEFORE_ENTRY,
  VALIDITY_DAYS_AFTER_ENTRY,
  STAY_DAYS,
  STAY_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_DAYS,
  EXTENSION1_GRACE_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_DAYS,
  EXTENSION2_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_BORDER_VISA,
  IS_MULTIPLE_ENTRY_VISA,
  VIOLATION_GRACE_DAYS,
  IS_ARCHIVED,
  JOB_CLOSE_AFTER_DAYS,
  IS_ALLOWED_FOR_ESTAB_QUOTA, 
  REPLACE_WITH_VISA_TYPE_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
order by visa_type_id,environment_name